# Solr : conserve hyphen word for suggest

Tags: filter, solr, schema

I use Solr 3.3. and I need to use suggest component to make an autocomplete.

I would like to conserve word with hyphen to make suggestion  (for example : "Wi-fi")

For differents field type configuration I have word "wifi" or "wi" .

Someone knows which filter can make this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

How does your schema look like (the autocomplete type)?
You could use solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory. It doesn't tokenize on extraneous characters like hyphens.

If you want to remove these characters, you need to use solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory, solr.PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory or even creating your own custom Tokenizer.